# How change the layout component in Tapestry 5 pages at runtime?

Tags: tapestry

I have one layout component for all my pages, I want to switch this component based on the user desire. I don't want to add a property to each page to return the current layout component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a fixed number of layouts, you can use blocks.  Your layout.tml would look something like:

```
   <t:delegate to="layout"/>

   <t:block id="layout1">
     <body>...</body>
   </t:block>

   <t:block id="layout2">
     <body>...</body>
   </t:block>
```

Your layout.java would have:

```
  public Object getLayout() {
    if (...) {
      return _layout1;
    } else {
      return _layout2;
    }
  }

  @Inject
  private Block _layout1;

  @Inject
  private Block _layout2;
```

Comment: Great,
But I don't want to put all the layouts in one .tml file..
Is there a way to delegate to a component???

Comment: Yes, the target of delegate can be a block or a component.  So you could just define a component for each layout you need.  I think you'd still need to list all those components in the main layout.tml but the html could be in the individual components.